# How come my Antlr ParseTree is null? / How come calling AbstractParseTreeVisitor.visit(ParseTree) is null?

Tags: java, antlr4, parse-tree

I am building an interpreter using Antlr in Java, and I come across a NullPointerException. The file I made it read is not empty, yet the ParseTree and AbstractParseTreeVisitor.visit(ParseTree) are null, and I don't know what went wrong.

I have been trying to call the contents of `progVisitor.visit(antlrAST)` and it is null when I printed it. When I put this in a variable and pass it as a parameter for another class, it returns a NullPointerException.

At the same time, printing the parse tree `antlrAST` gives me a `[]`. I am not sure where the problem lies, because printing the parse tree dot get text - `antlrAST.getText()` - prints the entire content just fine.

Below is the relevant code:

Snippet from main class:

```
    public void parse() {
        String fileName = "code.txt";
        MachDefParser parser = getParser(fileName);
        //tell antlr to build a parse tree
        //parse from start symbol 'prog'
        ParseTree antlrAST = parser.prog();
        System.out.println("Parse Tree: " + antlrAST);
        
        //create visitor to convert parse tree into Program/Expression object
        AntlrToProgram progVisitor = new AntlrToProgram();
        Program prog = progVisitor.visit(antlrAST);
        System.out.println("Parse Tree Content:\n" + antlrAST.getText());
        System.out.println(prog == null);

        ExpressionProcessor ep = new ExpressionProcessor(prog.getExpressions());
        for(String evaluation: ep.getEvaluationResults()) {
            System.out.println(evaluation);
        }
    }
    
    private static MachDefParser getParser(String fileName) {
        MachDefParser parser = null;
        
        try {
            CharStream input = CharStreams.fromFileName("src//" + fileName);
            MachDefLexer lexer = new MachDefLexer(input);
            CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
            parser = new MachDefParser(tokens);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        return parser;
    }
```

```
public class AntlrToProgram extends MachDefBaseVisitor<Program> {
    public AntlrToProgram() {

    }

    public Expression visitProgram(MachDefParser.ProgContext ctx) {
        Program prog = new Program();
        
        AntlrToExpression exprVisitor = new AntlrToExpression();
        //System.out.println(ctx.getChildCount());
        //helper visitor for transforming each subtree into Expression object
        for(int i = 0; i < ctx.getChildCount(); i++) {
            if(i == ctx.getChildCount()-1) {
                // last child of start symbol prog is EOF
                //do not visit child and attempt to convert to Expression object
            }
            else {
                prog.addExpression(exprVisitor.visit(ctx.getChild(i)));
                System.out.println("Adding to prog: " + exprVisitor.visit(ctx.getChild(i)).toString());
            }
        }
        
        return prog;
    }
}
```

```
import java.util.*;

public class Program extends Expression {
    private List<Expression> expressions;
    
    public List<Expression> getExpressions() {
        return expressions;
    }
    
    public Program() {
        this.expressions = new ArrayList<>();
    }
    
    public void addExpression(Expression e) {
        expressions.add(e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seeing your parser rule is called `prog`, the this:

```java
public Expression visitProgram(MachDefParser.ProgContext ctx)
```

is not a valid overridden visit-method. It should be named `visitProg` and must return a `Program`, not an `Expression`:

```java
@Override
public Program visitProg(MachDefParser.ProgContext ctx)
```

Comment: I have found a different solution to my problem, but thank you for helping! This is my first time asking in Stack Overflow and I really appreciate the help. :)

Answer (score -1):

What is your different solution ?

Reply to myself for everyone:

Each time a `TerminalNode` is called the `defaultValue` is redefined to null.

To change this behavior, in my `Visitor` I have overloaded `visitChildren` and `defaultResult` this way:

```java
private Value currentResult = Value.of("");

@Override
public Value visitChildren(final RuleNode node) {
    final Value value = super.visitChildren(node);
    this.currentResult = value;
    return value;
}

@Override
protected Value defaultResult() {
    return currentResult;
}
```